when i pressed 'Desktop Sites' after login, i got a message route error
after i pressed Dekstop Sites i got message error like this:
Cannot GET /login/api/send-login
This is my Route:
const router = require('express').Router();
const {login} = require('../modelController');
const verifyUser = require('../middleware/verify');

router.get('/', verifyUser.isLogout, login.loginPage);
router.post('/api/send-login', verifyUser.isLogout, login.loginAuth);

module.exports = router;

and this is my model-controller:
const connection = require('../configs/database'); 

const mysql      = require('mysql');
const pool       = mysql.createPool(connection);

pool.on('error',(err)=> {
    console.error(err);
});

module.export = {
    loginAuth(req, res) {
        const username = req.body.username;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const status = req.body.stats;
    
        if (username && password && status) {
            let query = '';
            let table = '';
    
            if (status === 'AKTIF') {
                table = 'login_siswa';
            } else if (status === 'ADMIN') {
                table = 'admin';
            } else {
                // Handle jika status tidak valid
                return res.redirect('/login?status=error&message=Statusmu%20tidak%20valid!');
            }
    
            // Query SQL dengan placeholder untuk nilai username, password, dan status
            query = `SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND status = ?`;
    
            pool.query(query, [username, password, status], function (error, results) {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    // Handle kesalahan query
                    return res.redirect('/login?status=error&message=Terjadi%20kesalahan%20saat%20mengautentikasi%20pengguna');
                }
                
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    const user = results[0];
                    req.session.loggedin = true;
                    req.session.id_login = user.id_login;
                    req.session.username = user.username;
                    req.session.status = user.status;
    
                    // Redirect pengguna ke halaman yang sesuai berdasarkan status pengguna
                    if (user.status === 'ADMIN') {
                        return res.redirect('/admin'); 
                    } else if (user.status === 'AKTIF') {
                        return res.redirect('/'); 
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle jika akun tidak ditemukan
                    return res.redirect('/login?status=error&message=Akun%20tidak%20ditemukan!');
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Handle jika data pengguna tidak lengkap
            return res.redirect('/login?status=error&message=Harap%20masukkan%20nama%20pengguna,%20kata%20sandi,%20dan%20status!');
        }
    } 
}

I dont know what happens here, i really confused to solve this bug, please helppp, i've try many things for this error code, and all is normal if i didnt pressed Desktop Sites Button.
I hope thats 'annoying' message is disappear
